# Constructing sink bowls in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

The player called dataless is well known for his enormous farms. Many of these feature a giant pool of water at the bottom that collects all of the farm's drops and funnels them to the center point.

I can't figure out how these sink bowls are constructed. He has one lets play that shows him building a small one with only one level, and he mentions they're very tricky and it's all too easy to turn the whole thing into source blocks. In any case the procedure he shows isn't well explained and I've never found any good tutorials on this, and especially not the multi level ones (his cactus farm uses pools that fall several levels down, with a total width that must be over 25 blocks.)

Does anyone know how to build these, preferably to an arbitrary size? I know there are probably particular dimensions that need to be followed but I'd like to be able to add any number of rings to make the pool larger.

[Dataless's Cactus Farm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cERbupGcwdY)

[Constructing a smaller sinkbowl](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8y66HodGKV0)

Comment: Can you add a link to the video in question?

Comment: @Ben Added both videos mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Level 0:

- A hopper to collect everything.

Level 1:

- Build a 17x17 platform out of solid blocks
- Leave a hole in the middle, directly above the hopper.

Level 2:

- Build a ring of solid blocks around the outside edge
- Put a solid block in each corner of the remaining 15x15 space
- Put two solid blocks along the exposed edges of the corner blocks
- Fill the rest of the edges with source blocks.  -

Thus, your level 2 will look like:

```
#################
#**SSSSSSSSSSS**#
#*             *#
#S             S#
#S             S#
#S             S#
#S             S#
#S             S#
#S      X      S#
#S             S#
#S             S#
#S             S#
#S             S#
#S             S#
#*             *#
#**SSSSSSSSSSS**#         
#################      

#: Any solid block
*: Any solid block
S: Water source block
X: this point is directly over the hopper
```

To create the next level of your "sink":

- Continue to build out level two with rings of "#" until each side is eight # wide.
- On leve3, create an outer ring, leaving a seven-wide "shelf" all around the 15x15 hole in the middle that is the lower level of your sink.
- Again, put three * at each corner to prevent everything from turning into source blocks.
- Again, put source blocks along all the edges.

Repeat this process until you have the size/number of layers that you want.

Comment: The key is to never allow 2 sources to be directly diagonal to each other